# Mobile Development: Same or Different Sites?

Tags: mobile, mobile-website

I am considering developing a mobile edition of a web site for an application, and I'm considering whether to revamp my existing site to work for mobile, or create separate web sites.  It seems to me even though some tout the benefits of CSS's capabilities, separate web sites is the way to go.  Although devices like the IPAD and other 10" devices can support a full screen view, handling support for a limited view for devices with a 4" or 7" screen is a good way to go?

Factoring in phones, tablets, notebooks, and other third party devices, do you think its possible to use the same site across web and mobile environments, or definitely consider a separate site?

Comment: If you end up using separate sites, please remember to have the redirects between them (if any) point to the same page on the site, rather than going to the main page. http://xkcd.com/869/

Comment: Yup, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: There is an question about [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844020/way-to-do-content-adaptation-to-mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, this will come down to the individual preferences of your site's visitors.

Personally, when I visit a site on my phone, I get annoyed when I'm automatically redirected to some mobile version.  When I access the site in such a manner, I'm usually trying to look up something quickly -- not looking to learn how to navigate around an essentially different site.

So, I would say that if you do design a different site for mobile users, attempt to stay true in some ways to your original layout, and don't vastly change the reorganization or URLs.

Having said that, I'd still say the better route would be to change your current design slightly so that it works well on both.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

> Factoring in phones, tablets, notebooks, and other third party devices, do you think its possible to use the same site across web and mobile environments, or definitely consider a separate site?

Absolutely, yes. Lots of great examples at http://responsivewebdesigns.tumblr.com/